# python how to add all elements of a list together

Tags: python, list, addition

if I had  a list

```
results = ['1','4','73','92']
```

how do I get that list to call on itself and add all elements together?
the elements have to be strings

Comment: `sum(map(int, results))`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. Before posting, try to break a problem down into logical steps. *After checking for existing duplicates*, try asking a separate, *specific* question about each part *where you are stuck*. In this case, there are three clear sub-problems: 1) how do we convert a string to an integer? 2) Once we know how to do that, how do we repeat that for all the strings, making a list of integers? 3) Now that we have that list, how do we add up the numbers? Each of these is a common duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using a list comprehension + *sum* operator:

```
sum([float(num) for num in results])
```

**Note that it's safer to use *float()* instead of *int()* since your elements may include decimals.**

Comment: `float()` has its own limitations; it will not accurately represent large integers, and floating-point values [aren't actually decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, good to know the details. However, in this use case, float will almost always do better than int.

Answer (score 2):

map `str` to `int` and sum it

```
results = ['1','4','73','92']
sum(map(int, results))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to convert the list of strings to a list of ints, then use the sum function to add all of the integers up.

```py
results = ['1','4','73','92']
sum([int(x) for x in results]) # 170
```

Comment: As Dina said in another comment, you should use `float` instead of `int` here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

First, create a variable for the total:

```
total = 0
```

Next, loop through all elements in the list:

```
for result in results:
```

Then, check if the string is a number:

```
if result.isnumeric():
```

Finally, add the result to the total:

```
total += int(result)
```

This results in the final code of:

```
total = 0
for result in results:
    if result.isnumeric():
        total += int(result)
```